# Change font color as the user types in RichTextBox 

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I want to create a simple text editor but supports multicolor font like a "Compiler"

Assume my program keywords are: "dog","cow","cat","bird"

I have a RichTextBox that implements TextChanged event.

now, My problem is I don't know how to change the font color when a keyword is encountered.

Example String: `A Big Dog and a Cat`

Dog will be color RED while cat will be color GREEN.

Comment: Just check this out http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/SyntaxRichTextBox.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how effecient this will be when you have massive amounts of text, but it works fairly well to the extent that I have tested it.

```
private void CheckKeyword(string word, Color color, int startIndex)
{
    if (this.richTextBox1.Text.Contains(word))
    {
        int index = -1;
        int selectStart = this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart;

        while ((index = this.richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(word, (index + 1))) != -1)
        {
            this.richTextBox1.Select((index + startIndex), word.Length);
            this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = color;
            this.richTextBox1.Select(selectStart, 0);
            this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
}

private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.CheckKeyword("dog", Color.Red, 0);
    this.CheckKeyword("cat", Color.Green, 0);
}
```